# Horizontal and vertical both side scroll carousel effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

How can I make a horizontal and vertical both side scroll carousel effect?

[Example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irk3T.png)

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @PiyushPatel I already implement i - carousel  but how can i manage two i courasal. I set two courasal one is Horizontal and another is vertically bu how can i make both courasal to scrollable.

Comment: Then its different from your actual question, You should mention your issue with the code, what have you done and what's not working.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using UITableView.

1) Take a UITableView

2) Create a Custom cell

3) Implement iCarousel into Custom Cell and manage it.